# MySQL joins and selecting from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL Workbench, and I have the following question:

Using the employees data, create select queries that will provide the following information:
Show a list of employees and what department they are in

- Columns: Employee Name, Department Name

I have two statements which provide the exact same return, but it's 1000 rows! Am I doing this "join" properly?

```
SELECT 
    departments.dept_name, employees.last_name, employees.first_name 
FROM 
    departments, employees
WHERE 
    departments.dept_name = employees.departments.dept_name;
```

and

```
SELECT
    dept_name, last_name, first_name
FROM
    departments
INNER JOIN
    employees
ON
    departments.dept_name = employees.departments.dept_name;
```

Comment: The second method is correct.  The first is archaic and like writing your queries in Middle English.

Comment: Both are correct however the 2nd approach is much more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables employees and departments are always many to many. Therefore, we need input table between them, which has columns id_emp and id_dep or more often 4 column, id_emp, id_dep, from, to. After that, your question is clear and we can speak about.

Example:
Tables:

```
employees                     emp_dep                     departments
id_emp   first_name           id  id_emp  id_dep          id_dep   name
1        John                  1   1        1               1      Finacial
2        Elsa                  2   2        2               2      Human res
```

Note: id_emp & id_dep in table emp_dep can't be together primary key beacause every employee can work many times again in same department.

Query on 3 table:

```
SELECT  e.first_name, 
        d.name
FROM    (employees e
        INNER JOIN emp_dep ed ON e.id_emp = ed.id_emp)
INNER JOIN departments d ON ed.id_dep = d.id_dep;
```

Output:

```
first_name     name
John           Financial
Elsa           Human res
```

SQL for create this database and table:

```
CREATE DATABASE employees_dep;
CREATE TABLE employees (id_emp INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE departments (id_dep INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE emp_dep (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, id_emp INT, id_dep INT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but the second is better.

Answer (score 1):

Both are same. However second one would be faster given large volume of data, but won't matter on small sized tables.